# Progress Listener in AWS 2.x for multipart uploading

Tags: java, amazon-s3, upload

I have recently upgraded the aws sdk of my project from 1.11 to 2.20
I wrote a code for multipart upload of a file into aws s3 bucket.
I previously used ProgressListener although I am not able to use it once I have upgraded as the import paths show error. I just want to log the progress of the multipart upload. I have searched for a alternate but I wasn't able to find one. My code is as follows:

```
public Info upload(String bucketname, String filePath, InputStream in, long length, String key, String secret, boolean isPublic) throws Exception {
    Region clientRegion = Region.AP_NORTHEAST_1;

    S3AsyncClient amazonS3 = S3AsyncClient.create();
    try {

        if (null == key || key.isEmpty()) {
            LogHelper.logInfo(String.format("Connecting using IAM role..."));
            amazonS3 = S3AsyncClient.builder()
                        .credentialsProvider(DefaultCredentialsProvider.create())
                        .region(clientRegion)
                        .build();
        } else {
            AwsCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = StaticCredentialsProvider.create(AwsBasicCredentials.create(key, secret));

            amazonS3 = S3AsyncClient.builder()
                        .region(clientRegion)
                        .credentialsProvider(credentialsProvider)
                        .build();
        }

        CreateMultipartUploadRequest createRequest = CreateMultipartUploadRequest.builder()
                    .bucket(bucketname)
                    .key(filePath)
                    .build();

        CompletableFuture<CreateMultipartUploadResponse> responseFuture = amazonS3.createMultipartUpload(createRequest);
        CreateMultipartUploadResponse createMultipartUploadResponse = responseFuture.join();
        String uploadId = createMultipartUploadResponse.uploadId();

        int partNumber = 1;
        List<CompletedPart> completedParts = new ArrayList<>();
        ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024 * 1024 * 5); // 5 MB byte buffer

        try {

            while (true) {
                int bytesRead = in.read(bb.array());
                if (bytesRead == -1) {
                    break; // End of input stream
                }

                UploadPartRequest uploadPartRequest = UploadPartRequest.builder()
                            .bucket(bucketname)
                            .key(filePath)
                            .uploadId(uploadId)
                            .partNumber(partNumber)
                            .build();

                AsyncRequestBody requestBody = AsyncRequestBody.fromByteBuffer(bb);

                CompletableFuture<UploadPartResponse> uploadPartFuture = amazonS3.uploadPart(
                            uploadPartRequest,
                            requestBody);

                UploadPartResponse partResponse = uploadPartFuture.join();

                CompletedPart part = CompletedPart.builder()
                            .partNumber(partNumber)
                            .eTag(partResponse.eTag())
                            .build();
                completedParts.add(part);

                partNumber++;
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.print("Error while reading InputStream");
            logger.error(e.getMessage());
        }

        System.out.println("bucket: " + bucketname);
        System.out.println("key: " + key);
        System.out.println("filepath: " + filePath);
        System.out.println("uploadId: " + uploadId);
        amazonS3.completeMultipartUpload(b -> b
                    .bucket(bucketname)
                    .key(filePath)
                    .uploadId(uploadId)
                    .multipartUpload(CompletedMultipartUpload.builder().parts(completedParts).build()));
        System.out.println("Upload complete.");
        return buildInfo(filePath, isPublic, length);
    } catch (SdkException e) {
        System.out.println("Error occurred while uploading file");
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new IOException("Error in putting S3 object", e);
    }
}
```

What I want is to log progress of the upload real time. eg: How many bytes has been uploaded so far etc. Any ideas or replacement of old ProgressListener for the newest aws sdk etc are welcome.